# LSL Wrapper for pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Newbie to Python and gaming. Is there an LSL (lab streaming layer) wrapper for pygame? I want to create a game using EEG signals to create a brain computer interface application. Any help will be deeply appreciated. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a LSL module for Python called [pylsl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylsl/1.10.3). You should be able to incorporate this into your game loop.

The following code was adapted from [this example](https://github.com/chkothe/pylsl/blob/master/examples/ReceiveDataInChunks.py):

```
from pylsl import StreamInlet, resolve_stream
import pygame

# first resolve an EEG stream on the lab network
streams = resolve_stream('type', 'EEG')

# create a new inlet to read from the stream
inlet = StreamInlet(streams[0])


# Pygame setup
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 320, 240

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

samples = []
while True:
    # get a new sample (you can also omit the timestamp part if you're not
    # interested in it)

    # Get a sample from the inlet stream
    sample, timestamp = inlet.pull_sample()
    samples.push(sample)

    #TODO: interpolate streamed samples and update game objects accordingly. 
    # You'll probably need to keep a few samples to interpolate this data.


    #TODO: draw game
    ...
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another possibility: engineers from the Foundation Campus Biotech Geneva have created a library using LSL for an online paradigm using EEG, called `NeuroDecode`.
It relies on `pylsl` and offers a higher-level implementation.

On my fork version, I dropped the (old) decoding functionalities in favor of improvements to the low-level functionalities, e.g. signal acquisition/visualization.

https://github.com/mscheltienne/NeuroDecode